# Multi-tenancy in the matrix.org for single homeserver with multi domain

Tags: matrix-synapse

I have deployed single instance running for home-server(synapse) with multiple domain attached to it as example.com and example1.com. 
I want to create the users like b1@example.com and b1@example1.com

Is is possible ?
Let me know advance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install multiple instances of synapse using python virtual environments. Configure each instance to listen only on localhost, on different ports. Then use an nginx reverse proxy to direct traffic to the correct instance based on the domain name requested.

Answer (score 1):

As far my knowledge goes this is currently not possible.

Whenever you setup a Matrix Synapse homeserver you define a unique name (=domain). See in the [Synapse docs](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse):

> The server name determines the "domain" part of user-ids for users on
>   your server: these will all be of the format @user:my.domain.name. It
>   also determines how other matrix servers will reach yours for
>   Federation.  ... Beware that the server name cannot be changed later.